# javaNullPointer on display.getRotation()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, accelerometer, android-sensors, displayobject

After having comment all my code to know from where the error was, i found that it came from mDisplay.getRotation().
The general idea of my code is to get the good information from the accelerometer when it's in any orientation.
Here's my code

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Récupérer les valeurs du capteur
    float x, y, z;
    String s1 = "stringX", s2 = "stringY", s3 = "stringZ";

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        switch (mDisplay.getRotation()) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            x = event.values[0];
            y = event.values[1];
            s1 = "" + x;
            s2 = "" + y;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            x = -event.values[1];
            y = event.values[0];
            s1 = "" + x;
            s2 = "" + y;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            x = -event.values[0];
            y = -event.values[1];
            s1 = "" + x;
            s2 = "" + y;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            x = event.values[1];
            y = -event.values[0];
            s1 = "" + x;
            s2 = "" + y;
            break;
        }
        z = event.values[2];   
        s3 = "" + z;

        tvx.setText(s1);
        tvy.setText(s2);
        tvz.setText(s3);

    }
}
```

I also have declared the display before the onCreate() with a

```
private Display mDisplay;
```

but i still have the javaNullPointer :s

Thank you guys.

Comment: Btw, an easier way to find out where an exception is thrown is to read the error messages in the logcat. They give you the exact file and line number.

Comment: I did but it wasn't very explicit and didn't give me a line number from the exact line problem, it only gave me a problem on the function onSensorChanged() :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
mDisplay = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hoan, you answered perfectly my problem!